# Induction Proof $T(n) = 9T(n/3) + n^2$

Tags: math, recurrence, proof, induction

How can I prove that the reccurence

> T(n) = 9T(n/3) + n<sup>2</sup>

leads to T(n) = O(n<sup>2</sup> log(n)) using the substitution method and a proof by induction? I’m not allowed to use the Master Theorem.

Using induction and assuming T(n) ≤ cn<sup>2</sup> log n, I got to the following point:

> T(n) = 9 * T(n/3) + n<sup>2</sup>
>
> ≤ 9c ( n<sup>2</sup> / 9 + log(n/3)) +n<sup>2</sup>
>
> = cn<sup>2</sup> + 9c log(n/3) + n<sup>2</sup>

Thank you.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the Master Theorem here?

Comment: No, i have to Proof by induction

Comment: What are the policies for the class that you’re taking? Are you allowed to ask questions on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Yes, its even recommended

Comment: Can you show your intermediate work that got you to the inequality you came up with above?

Comment: Sure. T(n) = 9 * T(n/3) + n^2 <= 9c ( n^2/9 + log(n/3)) +n^2 = cn^2 + 9c * log(n/3) + n^2

Answer (score 1):

I think you've made a math error in your substitution. If we assume that T(n) ≤ cn<sup>2</sup> log n, then we'd get

> T(n) = 9T(n / 3) + n<sup>2</sup>
>
> ≤ 9(c(n / 3)<sup>2</sup> log(n / 3)) + n<sup>2</sup>
>
> = 9((1 / 9)cn<sup>2</sup> log (n / 3)) + n<sup>2</sup>
>
> = cn<sup>2</sup> log(n / 3) + n<sup>2</sup>

You're very close to having things complete at this point. As a hint, suppose that the logarithm is a base-3 logarithm. What happens if you then use properties of logarithms to simplify cn<sup>2</sup> log(n / 3)?

Comment: Thank you! Then I have cn^2 (log(n) - 1) + n^2 = cn^2 log(n) + (1 - c)log(n). Can I say that c has to be greater than 1 one? because then cn^2 log(n) + (1 - c)log(n) would be smaller than cn^2 log(n) and I would be done.

Comment: btw How do I write math content in Stackoverflow?

Comment: Alas, it’s hard. I’m using the HTML tags <sup> and <sub> for that.

Comment: Check your math. You’re not distributing the terms in the multiplication correctly.

Comment: And now can I assume that c is >= 1, so that im done?